# UEFI option for booting through USB is deleted after Ubuntu 16.04.2 installation (Dual boot with Windows 10) on Dell Vostro 3558

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, dell

UEFI option for booting from USB drive is deleted after Ubuntu 16.04.2 (64 bit) installation (Dual boot with Windows 10 64 bit) on Dell Vostro 3558.

I have used information from the following:

- http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN
- http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN

Resetting UEFI to default brings back the USB boot option again.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance: SRoy

Answer (score 0):

Some EFIs tend to corrupt their NVRAM-based boot options when new options are added, causing old ones to be deleted or causing the computer to become unable to detect external media and present them as options. This sounds like what you're seeing. Some things you might try include:

- **Reset the firmware** -- Resetting the firmware can clear the problem and enable you to get a fresh start. It sounds like you've done this and the problem is recurring whenever you add the Ubuntu entry back, but that's not 100% clear.
- **Update your firmware** -- You might try checking with the manufacturer to see if a firmware update is available. (Most manufacturers call these "BIOS updates," although we're talking about computers that use (U)EFIs, not BIOSes.) If you're lucky, there will be a firmware update that will fix the problem.
- **Report the bug to the manufacturer** -- They can't fix bugs they don't know about. To be sure, this will be very unlikely to produce a fix in the short term, but in the long term, reporting firmware bugs will help fix them for future models (and maybe even some current models). The manufacturer may also know of a workaround.
- **Use rEFInd** -- My [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) should detect boot loaders on both built-in hard disks and removable media, and build a menu showing everything it finds. (Give or take entries affected by options set in `refind.conf` and some loaders that are automatically hidden for various reasons.) Sometimes you must hit the Esc key to get rEFInd to re-scan for boot loaders to get those on external media to show up. Note that you can test rEFInd on a CD-R or USB flash drive if you don't want to risk installing it to your hard disk right away.

Comment: Thanks 
- the problem IS recurring whenever the dual boot setup is done (adding the Ubuntu entry back).
- A firmware update is not available.
- The device is out of warranty, hence logged it in the Dell community forums - slightly convoluted process there.. :-(

Comment: What I have done now (workaround): Before setting up dual boot, I have copied the same entry (booting from USB) on the BIOS screen to make a dummy entry (with a different name), and I have disabled (unticked) it.This way (I have noticed that) the real entry goes, but the dummy entry stays, so if I need a USB boot in future I'll have to enable this (dummy) entry